# flask-mail AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I am trying to use flask.ext.mail to send email, however I am getting the following error. I followed a number of tutorials and they all seem to be doing the same thing, I have been looking around to see if anyone is getting this error and haven't found it.:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site xpackages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/aaronwishnick/Documents/Work/NewPersonalSite/app/views.py", line 27, in mail
    mail.send(msg)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Here is my **init**.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.mail import Mail
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com',
    MAIL_PORT = 25,
    MAIL_USE_TLS = False,
    MAIL_USE_SSL = False,
    MAIL_USERNAME = 'gmail_username',
    MAIL_PASSWORD = 'gmail_password'
)
mail = Mail(app)
from app import views
```

And mail function:

```
email = request.args.get('email')
name = request.args.get('name')
message = request.args.get('message')
msg = Message("Message from your site",
              sender=email,
              recipients=["aaronwishnick@gmail.com"])
msg.body = message
mail.send(msg)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You named your *view* `mail` as well:

```
  File "....", line 27, in mail
```

This is found when you refer to `mail` in your view, not the `Mail()` instance. Rename the view or rename the reference to the `Mail()` object.

Rename your view to `send_mail` for example:

```
def send_mail():
    email = request.args.get('email')
    name = request.args.get('name')
    message = request.args.get('message')
    msg = Message("Message from your site",
                  sender=email,
                  recipients=["aaronwishnick@gmail.com"])
    msg.body = message
    mail.send(msg)
```